# Tools to speed the generation of locale files (for rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization, macros, automation

I'm involved in preparing a pre-existing rails application for translation - going through the files under `app/views/`, finding the text, making a key in `config/locales/de.yml` (in this case), copying the text into `de.yml`, and putting `t("key")` in the view file. Repeat hundreds, maybe thousands of times. This is very tedious.

I don't think it can be fully automated, but the key things I need to do are select the text and give it a key.

So does anyone know of a tool that will automate the rest of the steps? I want to select the text, hit a key combo, type in a key, and the tool will put a key in the `de.yml` file, append the text, and put `t("key")` in place of the text that was selected.

My only key requirement is that it should run on Linux. I'm a vim user, but I'll learn Emacs if that is the best way to do it. I'll even install Eclipse if that is the best way ... I imagine that vim or emacs macros should easily be able to do the amount of work I'm asking for.

Anyone? Please?

With a bit of googling, I've managed to find a [textmate plugin](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/Rails-I18n-plugin-translation-on-the-fly-with-TextMate.html) which would be near perfect if I had a Mac and Textmate. Something similar would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Normally for those cases I use, I18n::Backend::Database (ActiveRecord Adapter for storing translations in the database). This has one major advantage that might also be helpful for your case, I can store translations without the key syntax.

Suppose you have this text `<%= link_to 'Das ist ein Link Text', root_url %>`
You could transform it to this with I18n::Backend::Database `<%= link_to t('Das ist ein Link Text'), root_url %>`.

Using this you could create a quick Textmate/Emacs/Vim shortcut to just basiclly wrap the t() around a string.

Does that solve your problem?